# Passing id and finding the element in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm extremely new to JavaScript and am stumped on this one.  I'm trying to send the `ClientID` of a `Control` to a js function.  The function should then find the element and get the `Control's` value.  To note: I am using a master page, and the `Control` I am passing the `ClientID` of is in a `UserControl`.

ASP:

```
//code here

<asp:TableCell runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="variableDDL"/>
    //some ListItems
</asp:Tablecell>

//more cells here

<asp:TableCell runat="server">
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="iButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/iButton.png" OnClientClick="iButtonClick(<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>);"/>
</asp:TableCell>

//code here
```

.js:

```
function iButtonClick(ClientID)
{
    var v = document.getElementById(ClientID);
    var val = v.value;
    alert(val);
}
```

Every time I click the button, nothing happens.  Changing the sent parameter to `<%#variableDDL.ClientID%>` does the same thing.  Changing it to `'<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>'` or `'<%#variableDDL.ClientID%>'` gives a null pointer error since it can't find the object.  The script is referenced correctly, and does fire if I change it to not accept a parameter and just produce an alert.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: The requested code is shown below.

ASP UserControl:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable fields = (DataTable) Session["fields"];
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        variableDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(fields.Rows[i]["Field"].ToString(), fields.Rows[i]["Field"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Rendered OnClick HTML:
`'<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>'` produces

```
onclick="iButtonClick(&#39;&lt;%=variableDDL.ClientID%>&#39;);"
```

`<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>` produces

```
onclick="iButtonClick(&lt;%=variableDDL.ClientID%>);"
```

`'<%#variableDDL.ClientID%>'` produces

```
onclick="iButtonClick(&#39;&lt;%#variableDDL.ClientID%>&#39;);"
```

`<%#variableDDL.ClientID%>` produces

```
onclick="iButtonClick(&lt;%#variableDDL.ClientID%>);"
```

Comment: also what does the code in the Page_Load look like..? do you have any code that checks if(IsPostBack){ } ?

Comment: The Page_Load of the UserControl, the ContentPage, or the MasterPage?

Comment: the one where that code above is .. is that the UserControl control or your main ContentPage..?

Comment: It is from the UserControl.  I don't have anything in the Page_Load, but the Page_Init is now shown.

Comment: Take a look in the rendered HTML source and see what the button's `OnClick` attribute is.

Comment: The rendered HTML has been added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of it,

```
OnClientClick="iButtonClick(<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>);"
```

is getting rendered literally - it's not replacing the contents of the angle brackets.

Try

```
OnClientClick='iButtonClick("<%=variableDDL.ClientID%>");'
```

Note the single quotes for the property - I think this *does* make a difference - and the double quotes so the result becomes a JavaScript string literal.

If this doesn't work, you might have to set

```
iButton.OnClientClick = "iButtonClick('" + variableDDl.ClientID + "');";
```

in an event in your codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not against jQuery, you could easily perform this operation by adding an identifying class to your select element, since it gets a unique client id.

```
<select id="variableDDL" class='varddl'>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<button id="btn1" type="button">Click here</click>


$("#btn1").click(function(e){
  var v = $(".varddl:first-child").val();
  alert('Value of '+ $(".varddl:first-child").attr('id') + 'is ' + v);

});
```

[Click here to view the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/CGYDS/1/)

UPDATE: Pure JS Version

```
function btnClick(e){
   //Select the first occurance, [0]
   var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('varddl')[0];
      if(ele){
         //There's the value
         var val = ele.value;
         alert(val);
      }
}
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = btnClick
```

;

[Here is the JS Only Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/VkYFe/)

Comment: I'm not against using it at all, I'm just completely unfamiliar with it. I'll try adding this in and see if it works. Thank you for the suggestion, this looks much simpler.

Comment: @Tucker no problems. I've had to use this technique with ASP.NET WebForms before, works fantastic.  You just special class the fields you need to work with.  I will update it with a pure JS version after the morning coffee decides to start it's day...

Answer (score 0):

This is how ASP.Net works: you cannot use servercode (<%%>) inside ASP.Net WebControls.

You can solve this by putting the ClientID directly in the javascript code:

```
function iButtonClick()
{
    var v = document.getElementById('<%= variableDDL.ClientID %>');
    var val = v.value;
    alert(val);
}
```

You can also pass an object directly in the OnClientClick, with the restriction that you can only send the object itself:

```
OnClientClick="ButtonClick(this);"
```